# sql view performance optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization, query-performance

I have a view which has the below definition

```
create view mydashboard as
SELECT distinct 
       cu.CrimeID, 
       ad.DeptID, 
       ad.CrimeDate, 
       cd.DeptIncidentID, 
       ad.crime,
       u.username 
from alldatescrimes ad
inner join crimeslist cl
on
ad.crime =  cl.crime
inner join users u
on
u.DeptID = ad.DeptID
left join crimelookup cu
on cu.CrimesListID = cl.CrimeListID
left join crimesdetail cd
on
ad.CrimeDate = cast(cd.CrimeDate as date)
and
ad.DeptID = cd.DeptID
and
cu.CrimeID = cd.CrimeID
```

My problem is that If I put a where clause outside the view, the query runs very slowly. See the below example

```
select *
from mydashboard 
where

(username  = 'john'
or
DeptIncidentID is null
)
and
CrimeDate = '2014-06-16'
```

On the contrary If I put the same where clause inside the view, the query runs very fast..like in 2-3 seconds

My question is what steps can I take so that the query runs fast if I put the where clause outside view. I am using this view in a report and the query runs real slow

Regards
Arif

Comment: Do you have any indexes set up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL has two options to process a view that is used inside a query: [`MERGE` or `TEMPTABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/view-algorithms.html).

> For `MERGE`, the text of a statement that refers to the view and the view definition are merged such that parts of the view definition replace corresponding parts of the statement.
>
> For `TEMPTABLE`, the results from the view are retrieved into a temporary table, which then is used to execute the statement.

Because of the `DISTINCT` clause in the view definition, MySQL cannot use the `MERGE` algorithm. It must falback to the less efficient `TEMPTABLE` algorithm.

The temporary table has no index, therefore the whole table must be scanned to process your outer `WHERE` conditions.

You may want to remove the `DISTINCT` clause from the view definition, and put it in your outer query instead.

Comment: Actually, the `DISTINCT` clause could be superfluous altogether, as you seem to select a "unique" column from every table involved.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit long for a comment.

MySQL does a poor job of optimizing views.  In fact, one part of the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-restrictions.html) starts:

> > View processing is not optimized:

One possible issue is that MySQL has determined that a temporary table is needed for the view.  If so, all the processing needs to be done.  Then at the very last stage, the `where` clause is being added.  [Here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-algorithms.html) is more information on "merge" versus "temporary tables" for views.